# Overriding @LastModifiedDate field with provided Date in springboot mongodb auditing

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, auditing

When performing migration of legacy data to a springboot project it is sometimes crucial, to use the same Date for auditing fields such as **createdDate** and **lastModifiedDate**.

When using mongodb auditing, it is possible to override the createdDate with a custom date using **@CreatedDate** annotation.

However, the same is not true for **@LastModifiedDate**.

Mongodb auditing always saves the document with the actual Date the document was modified on instead of overriding it with the provided date.

Using **@LastModifiedDate** is there a way to save **LastModifiedDate** with the provided date similar to when using **@CreatedDate**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the Spring's auditing behavior by overriding the value of the field using reflection:

```
Field field = DomainObject.class.getDeclaredField("lastModifyDate");
field.setAccessible(true);
LocalDateTime time = LocalDateTime.now().minus(8, ChronoUnit.MINUTES);
field.set(domainObject, Date.from(time.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
mongoTemplate.save(domainObject);
```